# Multiple filtering

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'd like to filter a list of elements with their title attributes.

```
<img name="chrome_brillant" title="chrome brillant" src=#">
<img name="chrome_brillant" title="chrome red mat" src=#">
<img name="chrome_brillant" title="chrome jaune" src=#">
```

Using a search field (text input), i can look up for keywords in the title attribute.

But i would i find the second item, with "red chrome" as an input, and hide all the other items ?

Thanks,
Jérémie.

Comment: You should explain more your problem and also include your code. It will be great to add also a JSFiddle to check what's your problem.

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score -1):

```
$('img').filter(":contains('red'), :contains('chrome')")
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered poor-quality content on Stack Overflow.  Please provide information about *why* this answers the question.